# Python - loading file - dictionary

Tags: python, class, function, dictionary

i'm trying to write a function that will turn my text file into a dictionary with subsets. The text document that i have loaded so far is displayed as showed:

```
101
102
103
201, John Cleese, 5/5/12, 5/7/12
202
203, Eric Idle, 7/5/12, 8/7/12
301
302
303
```

The outcome of the function should get the information loaded and return it as:

```
[('101', None), ('102', None), ('103', None),
('201', Guest(John Cleese, 05/05/12, 05/07/12)), ('202', None),
('203', Guest(Eric Idle, 07/05/12, 08/07/12)), ('301', None),
('302', None), ('303', None)]
```

I've been trying isdigit but to no avail. I managed to get the last room (303) to nearly function though.

```
def load_rooms(self, filename):
    fd = open(filename, 'rU')
    self._rooms = {}
    for i in fd:
        i = i.rstrip()
        print i

    if i.isdigit():
        self._rooms[i] = None
        print self._rooms
    else:
        print i
```

displays

```
101
102
103
201, John Cleese, 5/5/12, 5/7/12
202
203, Eric Idle, 7/5/12, 8/7/12
301
302
303
{'303': None}
```

Oh wow, i just noticed that the room 303 is shown twice... Well my question is, how would i approach loading the text file? Would i have to make sure that all all the code is in format, or could i just write a function which would turn it into the dictionary with subsets? I'm quite new with dictionaries so a little help would be great. thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the `csv` module?

Comment: Why is ths tagged with tkinter? I see nothing related to Tkinter in the question.

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley sorry, your right. i'll try to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

class Guest(object):
  ...

data = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    tok = re.split(r'\s*,\s*', line.strip())
    if len(tok) > 1:
      guest = Guest(tok[1], tok[2], tok[3])
    else:
      guest = None
    data.append((tok[0], guest))

print(data)
```

Implementing the `Guest` class is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Is this another function? Or would this code be under the load_file function? Sorry im just not quite sure where to place it, it could even be under the Guest class, however the function i am writing belongs to the another class.

Comment: You can place this code (minus the `Guest` class declaration and implementation) in a function wherever you need it. Just make sure to import the `Guest` class if it is located in a different module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need the `re` module

try this

```
def load_file( filename ):
    text = open( "data.txt" ).readlines()
    rooms = {}
    for line in text:
        room_data = line.strip( '\n' ).split( ',' )
        if len( room_data ) > 1:
            #rooms[room_data[0]] = room_data[1:]
            rooms[room_data[0]] = tuple( room_data[1:] )
        else:
            rooms[room_data[0]] = None

    return rooms
```

you mention dictionary in your title but your expected outcome is nested lists.

***Edit***

Answered?

Comment: the displayed is: {'201': [' John Cleese', ' 5/5/12', ' 5/7/12 '], '203': [' Eric Idle', ' 7/5/12', ' 8/7/12 '], '202': None, '301': None, '302': None, '303': None, '102': None, '103': None, '101': None}

Comment: yes {'KEY' : Value , ...} is a dictionary [(key,value),(key,value) is a nested lists used like a dictionary.

Comment: Is there a way to make the displayed be: {'key': (value)} instead of {'key': [value]}?

Comment: @AnthonyDo -> {'201': (' John Cleese', ' 5/5/12', ' 5/7/12'), '203': (' Eric Idle', ' 7/5/12', ' 8/7/12'), '202': None, '301': None, '302': None, '303': None, '102': None, '103': None, '101': None}

Comment: "if there isn't 4 items" `tuple(room_data[1:])`