# Assigning NoneType to Dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror, nonetype

I'm trying to assign `None` to a key in a dict, but I'm getting a TypeError:

```
self._rooms[g[0]] = None
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

My code is here:

```
r = open(filename, 'rU')
    for line in r:
        g = line.strip().split(',')
        if len(g) > 1:
            r1 = g[0]
            h = Guest(g[1], str2date(g[2]), str2date(g[3]))
            self._rooms.set_guest(r1, h)
        else:
            self._rooms[g[0]] = None
    r.close()
```

Before it would let me assign, but not it won't. It is strange.

Comment: Nice question +1, you asked a clear question, gave us a code snippet without flooding us and gave us a clear traceback!

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to this post yesterday, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600746/python-loading-file-dictionary.  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Also, be careful here.  Stackoverflow is not nice for editing python code -- Your indentation between the first two lines is not quite right ;) -- If I got a nickle for every time my python indentation was wrong on SO, I'd probably have a couple dollars by now ...

Answer (score 13):

The exception clearly states `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment` this suggests that `self._rooms` is actually `None`

Edit:
As you said yourself

```
self._rooms = {}
```

or

```
self._rooms = dict()
```

Will do what you need to clear the dict

Comment: Or more likely, `self._rooms[g[0]]`, since there was no "'NoneType' object is unsubscribtable" TypeError raised.

Comment: Try `None[3]=4` In your interpreter you will get the exact same exception ^^

Comment: I stand corrected! That seems odd to me, though. Feels like the illegal subscript needs to be evaluated before Python can determine that we are trying to assign to None.

Comment: 'd = self._rooms
   self._rooms = d.clear()', This is meant to clear my dictionary when i load my file. If i just set it to 'self._rooms = dict()' will that do the same thing?

Comment: no its because `Something[4]` actually calls `__setitem__`, considering `None` specifically does NOT support any methods ever on anything that is where the exception should come from

Comment: @JakobBowyer `d.clear()` and `d={}` are not completely equivalent -- especially if `d` is a subclass of `dict` (which it appears to be since it has a `set_guest` method).  Also, it isn't the same if other objects reference `d` (which is probably less likely in this instance).

Comment: @Unistudent : I actually think that the way he's "clearing" the dictionary is the culprit in this case.  see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check that `self._rooms` is not `None`.

Assigning `None` as a value to a `dict`'s key actually works:

```
In [1]: dict(a=None)
Out[1]: {'a': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

From reading your comments to Jakob, I gather that the culprit is this line (not posted)

```
d = self._rooms 
self._rooms = d.clear()
```

`d.clear()` will clear the dictionary `d` (and `self._rooms`) in place and return `None`.
Thus, all said an done, `d` is an empty dictionary and `self._rooms` is `None`.

The cleanest solution to this is:

```
self._rooms.clear()  #No need for assignment here!
```

especially since `self._rooms` appears to have inherited from `dict` -- so it may have other attributes that you don't want to lose by doing:

```
self._rooms={}  #Now this is just a dict, no longer has `set_guest` method!
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably complaining about `self._rooms`, which I suspect is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Because I assigned a value to `None` type with a key as shown below:

```py
x = None
x['y'] = "Hello" # Here
```

So to solve the error, I assinged a value to `dict` type as shown below:

```py
x = {}
x['y'] = "Hello" # Here
```

```py
x = dict()
x['y'] = "Hello" # Here
```